# how to sync iphone contacts with database?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, synchronization

I've an iphone app and a web app(in php ), i want to  synchronize contacts in iphone app with database records.(from both device and web app ie. user can add/update/delete contacts from device or web app and both database will sync.)

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more specific information before anyone can help you. Have you got any code yet?

Comment: i just want is that if user add/update a contact at either side then other side must be synchronized ie. if user add a contact in mysql database then it must reflect in device and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Use php-addressbook.sf.net, it includes a Exchange Interface to Sync your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear anyway I will give you some ideas

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );}
```

here the link for editing contacts and managing contacts
http://zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475